# What is the use of resistors or capacitors in a led strip?

Tags: pcb, schematics, led-strip

I own an [60 led/m ws2812 led strip](https://www.hellasdigital.gr/electronics/optoelectronics/ws2812b-5050-rgb-led-strip-5m-60leds-m-waterproof/). I noticed that every two leds there is an smd component.

- What type of component is this? Resistor or capacitor?
- In which signal is it connected to?
- If i connect the power supply in the middle of the strip, will it still work, or simply burn out?

The [component](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1179113/WORLDSEMI/WS2812B.html) is a capacitor from 5V to GND.
Can i still connect the power supply in the middle?

Thanks!

Comment: since we don't know your LED strip, it's impossible to tell with any certainty. But: you having access to the strip could with minimal measurement effort determine whether that is a resistor and capacitor yourself. Also: see the example schematic in the WS2812's datasheet, last page (god I hate that datasheet with a passion).

Comment: Just updated with the led strip link. Unfortunately it is an OEM one

Comment: How long is your strip? Powering from both ends is usually sufficient, if the voltage drop external to the strip is minimal. The WS2812 strips use constant current drivers, the LEDs in the middle can withstand a big voltage drop without affecting the brightness (~1V?).

Comment: @Mattman944 it is 4 meters long

Comment: On my strip, they are across Vcc and GND, so they are caps.

Comment: I have a 1 meter high-density strip, 144 LEDs/meter. I can power it from one side without problems. So, you should be able to power a 4 meter strip if you power both sides, if the losses are minimal in *your* wires.

Answer (score 0):

*If i connect the power supply in the middle of the strip, will it still work, or simply burn out?*

Yes, it should work. This would be the equivalent to cutting the strip in half and powering one from the front and the other from the back.

This assumes that you are good at soldering, the connection point is fragile, you can easily pull the pads off. It is better to use the factory connections.

Of course, the signal must attach to the appropriate end.